# How to proof $z^{n}-1= \prod_{k=1}^{n}({z- e^{ \frac{2 \pi i k}{n} } )}$

Tags: complex-analysis

i tried to rewrite as

$z^{n-1}+ \dots + 1 =\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}({z- e^{ \frac{2 \pi i k}{n} } )}$

and could not do much. Also, tried to use periodicity identity yet it did not fit in.

Comment: Prove that the $e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ are the $n$ distinct roots $z^n-1$. This for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: Hint : De Moivre's Theorem is helpful ( + remainder theorem for polynomials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any integer $r,$ $$\left(e^{2r\pi i/n}\right)^n=e^{2r\pi i}=1$$

But if $f(z)=z^n-1$

$f'(z)=nz^{n-1}$

Hence $f(z)$ can not have repeated roots

Again if $e^{2a\pi i/n}=e^{2b\pi i/n}\iff e^{2(a-b)\pi i/n}=1$

$\iff n|(a-b)\iff a\equiv b\pmod n$

So, the roots of $z^n=1$ are $e^{2r\pi i/n}, r\equiv0,1,\cdots,n-2,n-1\pmod n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$z^n=1\iff z=e^{\frac{2 ik\pi}{n}}$$
with  $k=0,...,n-1$.